# How to find a COM dll installation working back from the Interop dll

Tags: .net, windows, com-interop

I have a project that references a COM dll, and the Interop assembly is available and visible in my project, but I would like to locate the actual COM dll and dependencies, so that I can build a complete deployment package.

Short of just searching the registry in Regedit, is there anything else I can do to get a grip on this COM package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll always end up going to the registry. You can obtain CLSIDs from the interop, by looking for `[Guid]` attributes on classes. From these, you can look in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\<guid>\InprocServer32` for the location of the DLL.

The OleView tool -- included with Visual Studio -- is helpful for this. One you locate your COM class under "All Objects", it can show you all the relevant registry entries in one place.

Comment: Thanks @Tim.  Any idea where I can find that tool in VS 2010?

Comment: Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt window and type `oleview`. I found mine at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\oleview.exe.

Comment: for me, in windows 10 it was in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\<guid>\InprocServer32`